# Using AND OR Operators In The Same If Statement (Python)

Tags: python

So, I'm challenging myself to build an A.I enabled chess game. Right now I'm just working on the game logic taking an object oriented approach. It's proving to be a good way of going about it. However, while I was defining a method in my pawn object to capture another piece, I needed to use a long if..and..and..or statement. Now it's not preforming the way I need it to. I'm assuming that's because of a rule having to do with operators and how they evaluate together. I seem to remember something about this in one of my college IT courses I just finished. I did some testing on the algorithm and can confirm that the problem is contained in the last few expressions of the first line of the following elif statement :

#Checks to see if there is a piece in the desired move position. Each square is represented by (x,y) co-ordinates which are stored as an object property and entered into a dictionary with the piece name as the key and the square it occupies as the value.

```
elif checkSquare(peicePosition, move) == True and move[1] - self.position[1] == 1 and move[0] == self.position[0] + 1 or move[0] == self.position[0] - 1:
    self.position = move
    self.firstMove = False
    peicePosition[self.name] = self.position

    return print("Capptured Peice")
```

Comment: just put parentheses around them to set order precedence, same as any math equation

Comment: Add parentheses enveloping the tests, like `(a==b) or (d==c)`, that helps rule out a lot of potential problems.

Comment: " I did some testing on the algorithm and can confirm that the problem is contained in the last few expressions of the first line of the following elif statement :" Okay, so what actually is the problem? Did you try to test the code in isolation, for example by hard-coding some values for the `move` `self.position` etc. and looking for inputs that give the wrong output? Did you try putting `python operator precedence` into a search engine? Did you try using parentheses to clarify your intent?

Comment: Saying things like "Now it's not preforming the way I need it to." is not helpful for others; you should explain what happens and how that is different from what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Thanks, man. I'll try to be more specific next time.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).
Operator precedence is documented quite well in the official language definition and any tutorial on Boolean expressions, *including* parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into an order of operations issue. Just like the PEMDAS that we all learned in middle school (or some equivalent), all of the AND operations are performed before the OR. [This site](https://medium.com/@thoashook/operations-in-python-69bbbef781a4) details the order of operations for logic as well as math. Try adding some parentheses, just as the comments state.

Comment: Lol thanks guys. I feel stupid for not realizing that. Y'all rock!